# problems updating d3 map with slider

Tags: d3.js

I'm having problems updating a d3 map with a slider. The demo is at http://bricbracs.com/hh/

The csv file contains data for 3 random states each between the years 2010-2013. It should fill the corresponding state on the map with a scaled color and the rest black.  But you'll notice moving the slider back and forth the map is not updating properly and is filling as many as six states when there should only be three. For some reason it's not clearing out old data.

For example, the state of Texas keeps changing color even though the csv file has data for the year 2011 only. Yet when you move the slider to 2009 or 2014 where there is no data all the states are filled black which is correct.

What am I dong wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here is the csv file

```
year,state,value
2010,Georgia,460
2010,Illinois,401
2010,Montana,312
2011,Texas,202
2011,Georgia,500
2011,Montana,350
2012,New York,150
2012,Georgia,240
2012,Tennessee,500
2013,New York,100
2013,Georgia,300
2013,Illinois,75
```

Here is the function which initially loads the data.

```
d3.csv("expenses.csv", function(data) {
data1=data
data = data.filter(function(d) { return d.year == yr });
data.forEach(function(d) {   
  d.value = +d.value; 
});
            color.domain([
            d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }),
            d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value })
    ]);

d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) {  
    jsonx=json  

   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         dataState = data[i].state;
         dataValue = parseFloat(data[i].value);

          for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {
        jsonState = json.features[j].properties.name;   
        if (dataState == jsonState) {
            json.features[j].properties.value = dataValue;      
            break;              
        }
    }       
}

svg.selectAll("path")
     .data(json.features)
     .enter()
     .append("path")
     .attr("d", path)
     .style("stroke","#ccc")
     .style("fill", function(d) {

var value = d.properties.value;                         
    if (value) {
        return color(value);
    } else {
       return "#000";

                       }
 })

     })
});
```

Here is the update function which is called by the slider bar which should be filtering out the data by year.

```
function update() {
datax=data1
datax = datax.filter(function(d) { return d.year == yr });

 datax.forEach(function(d) {   
    d.value = +d.value; 
  });
            color.domain([
            d3.min(datax, function(d) { return d.value; }),
            d3.max(datax, function(d) { return d.value })
    ]);
 for (var i = 0; i < datax.length; i++) {
         dataState = datax[i].state;
         dataValue = (datax[i].value)

          for (var j = 0; j < jsonx.features.length; j++) {
        jsonState = jsonx.features[j].properties.name;  
        if (dataState == jsonState) {
            jsonx.features[j].properties.value= dataValue;      
            break;              
        }
    }                 
                   }

svg.selectAll("path")       
     .attr("d", path)
                         .style("fill", "#000") 
    .style("fill", function(d) {                     
            var value1 = d.properties.value;
    if (value1) {
        return color(value1);
    } else {
       return "#000";
                       }
 })
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not resetting the value of the `jsonx.features[j].properties.value`.

So you will need to reset all the `jsonx.features[j].properties.value`  to `undefined` **before** you set the value as per the filtered data.

```
for (var j = 0; j < jsonx.features.length; j++) {
    jsonx.features[j].properties.value = undefined;
  }
//code for setting the value as per the filter
for (var i = 0; i < datax.length; i++) {
    dataState = datax[i].state;
    dataValue = (datax[i].value);
    for (var j = 0; j < jsonx.features.length; j++) {
      jsonState = jsonx.features[j].properties.name;
      if (dataState == jsonState) {
        jsonx.features[j].properties.value = dataValue;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the reason why you see previous filtered values in the current filter when you move the slider.

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7nFDbe6rcQ7OrVzRI60n?p=preview)